# Possibility of determining the third side of a right angled triangle using given three parameters:

Tags: geometry, triangles

Suppose there are two arbitrary side lengths of a right angled triangle that are known to us. There are two possible cases here that I can see:

1. Either one of the side lengths given is the length of the hypotenuse.
2. Both the sides lengths given are the lengths of the legs of the right angled triangle

Now, additionally one arbitrary acute angle measure is also known. There are again two possible cases that I can see:

1. The angle lies between the two sides that are known to us (in which case it will then be
   confirmed that one of the sides given is the hypotenuse).
2. The angle does not lie between the two sides that are known to us (in which case it will
   then be confirmed that the sides lengths given are the lengths of the legs of the right
   angled triangle).

Now, I want to know if there is any possibility of determining the third side of the right angled triangle using the conditions given above (two arbitrary sides and one arbitrary acute angle) and without any additional conditions for eliminating the cases given above. If possible, please tell me the formulae/procedure to follow.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In a right triangle, if any one of the acute angles are known, then all 3 angles are known.  Further, if then any two of the sides are known, then regardless of whether one of the known lengths is the hypotenuse, the [Law of Cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines) can be applied.

Comment: I think you've left out the possibility that one side is the hypotenuse but the angle is not the angle between the two sides, Aaditya.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a$, $b$ are the given lengths of two sides and $\theta$ is the given acute angle, then $a$, $b$ are the legs of the triangle only if $\tan\theta=a/b$ or $\tan\theta=b/a$. Check that to see which case you are dealing with.